# How to bind Label class object returned from controller to $().html jquery to get html value of the label

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

//Controller

```
public Label CallbackPanelPartial()       
{    
     Label rb = new Label();`
     rb.ID = "dd";
     rb.Text = "aaa";       
     return rb; 
}
```

jQuery function to bind label as html content to view

```
function LoadFormGen(s,e) 
{

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("CallbackPanelPartial", "LoadForm")',
            beforeSend: function () {
                lpTimeslot.Show();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#genForm").html(response);

                    pcTimeslotHed.SetHeaderText('Load - [New]');

                pcTimeslotHed.Show();
                lpTimeslot.Hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm getting a result as System.Web.UI.WebControl.Label. What I want is to get the html content returned label.

Comment: `System.Web.UI.WebControl.Label` is web forms, not MVC!

Answer (score 1):

Label class will always return an Object not HTML

If you want to get HTML then

First Create an ActionResult which will return a Partial View with Label class Model. assign value accordingly

```
public ActionResult CallbackPanelPartial()       
{    
 Label rb = new Label();`
 rb.ID = "dd";
 rb.Text = "aaa";
 return PartialView(rb );
}
```

Create a Partial View with name `CallbackPanelPartial.cshtml` which will accept System.Web.UI.WebControl.Label type model

```
@model System.Web.UI.WebControl.Label
    @{

    }
    <Label id = "@Model.ID">@Model.Text</Label>
```

**Else code will remain same**

Comment: I want to add labels dynamically to the view according to the database value. That's why I have created Label in the controller.

Comment: I have made some changes in answer that will create lable dynamic as per model which you will send

Comment: How to use panel instead of label for the same scenario where two labels are there inside the panel

Comment: Will you please describe in detail what do you want ?